# Dropdown list not selecting value asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

```
  ddlBanAcc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
  string s = ddlBanAcc.SelectedValue;
  string[] words = s.Split('|');
  if (ddlBanAcc.SelectedIndex > 1)
  {
    query += "'and DtaLineAccountToDebit='" + words[0] + "'";
  }
```

On the ddlBankAcc (Dropdownlist selection) i am populating the Datagrid which is in the Update Panel

However the code is not executing and no value is getting selected by this statement `ddlBanAcc.SelectedValue;`

EDIT: HTML CODE

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                 <td>
                            Bank Account:
                        </td>
                        <td>
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlBanAcc" Width="160px" TaEvalex="3">
    </asp:DropDownList>

                        </td>
```

EDIT : how i am adding data in ddlBanAcc

```
DataTable dtbankaccount = oDBAccess.getDataTable("SELECT BkiAccountNb + ' | ' + BkiCurrency+ ' | ' +BkiAccountNb AS CONCATE  From VwCieBankAcc");
    ddlBanAcc.DataTextField = "CONCATE";
    ddlBanAcc.DataSource = dtbankaccount;

    ddlBanAcc.DataBind();
```

Comment: paste some more code from HTML section too so that we can go for solutions............

Comment: Have you selected an item in ddlBanAcc ? 
If you dont s.Split will fail.

Comment: yes i do select an item in ddlBanAcc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to check IsPostBack, and if it is do not make DataBind, because this is making the DropDownList to re-get all his values, and lost the selection.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
    ddlBanAcc.DataBind();
```

Especial on DropDownList that is keep his values on ViewState you need to use the IsPostBack to the full process that is fill in. And the final code will be:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dtbankaccount = oDBAccess.getDataTable("SELECT BkiAccountNb + ' | ' + BkiCurrency+ ' | ' +BkiAccountNb AS CONCATE  From VwCieBankAcc");
    ddlBanAcc.DataTextField = "CONCATE";
    ddlBanAcc.DataSource = dtbankaccount;

    ddlBanAcc.DataBind();
}
```

If for any other reason you need to make DataBind and change the content of the DropDownList even after his selection you can always get the post back value using the `Request.Form` as:

```
Request.Form[DromDownListID.UniqueID]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBanAcc" runat="server" DataTextField="" DataValueField="">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Try defining the DataTextField and DataValueField in the back end. This should help.

Comment: Give your respective DataTextField and DataValueField

Comment: Yes have seen try giving DataValueField also

Comment: i cant specify a DataValue field as in am concatenating the values and no specific column is being used to populate the Dropdownlist

Comment: For you using SelectedValue. So you need to have DataFieldValue

Comment: I have specified CONCATE as my DataValueField it still doesnt work

Comment: ok so while you concatinating it their would be one id column.?

Comment: See after concatenation the values are displayed in the ddlBankAcc i just one to compare the BkiAccountNb  that is the first value in the ddlBankAcc which i want to compare with the Database and populate my DataGrid

Comment: And What all is visible in dlBankAcc

Comment: SELECT BkiAccountNb + ' | ' + BkiCurrency+ ' | ' +BkiName AS CONCATE

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your `DropDownList` to get it to post back. I presume this is why the code is not executing.

Comment: No still not getting any values

Answer (score 0):

There is one more surprising issue that can cause this! My list values came from a database and the values had linefeed and carriage return: "\r\n". These values look like an innocent space, but actually they are not! My solution was to remove these hidden Char values. Hope it helps.