# To Display controls based on the dropdownlist selected item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For Dropdownlist items i have written the following code:

```
 protected void dropdowndatasrc()
{
    con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    string command = "select eventname from Events";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(command);
    dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, con);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("PayEvent");
    dataadapter.Fill(dt);
    DropDownList4.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList4.DataTextField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
  //  DropDownList4.DataValueField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
   DropDownList4.DataBind();
}
```

I have to display controls based on the value of the dropdownlist (in the access database there is a column named payevent in that it has Yes/No datatype if the selected item in the database have 'yes' means display controls if not no controls must be displayed)

I have tried this code but not worked

```
protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox11.Text = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text;
    con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    string query = "select payevent from Events where  eventname=@dropdownlist";
    con.Open();
    //string query="select payevent from Events";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dropdownlist", selectedtext);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string value = reader.GetValue((0)).ToString();
        TextBox11.Text = value.ToString();
        if (value == "True" || value == "true")
        { pnl.Visible = false; }
        else if (value == "False" || value == "false")
        { pnl.Visible = true; }



    }
}
```

**the table structure as follows:**

```
**eventname             payevent**
Work Shop       Yes
emsisoft workshop   Yes
ECE             No
CSE             No
```

Need help !!!

Comment: Hey. By "not worked", what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The usually issue is that you make databind on the dropdownlist again after the post back and the value is lost. So on page load, do not call the `dropdowndatasrc` on post back as:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
  dropdowndatasrc();
```

same issue: [Dropdown list not selecting value asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832344/dropdown-list-not-selecting-value-asp-net/12832949#12832949)